# Bool referenced from script not updating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bool called isDead in the script called Something which I can change in the inspector. I use Get Component to reference the bool in another script called main in which I call it isD, and use Debug.Log to see it in the console. When I start the script the console shows the correct state of the bool, but when I change the its value in the inspector the one in console stays the same.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isD;
    public GameObject Side;
    void Start()
    {
        isD = Something.GetComponent<Something>().isDead;
        Debug.Log(isD);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       Debug.Log(isD);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Something : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isDead;
    void Start()
    {
        isDead = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: becuase it's not reference ... bool is value type

Comment: Class `Something` doesn't have a static method `GetComponent`.

Comment: In general: You shouldn't `Debug.Log` in `Update`. This slows done your entire game (until a master build where the `Debug` calls are stripped off). Rather go to the Inspector, set it to [debug mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html). Then you can see all (serializable) private fields in the Inspector ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool` is a value type, so when you assign it, you are copying the value, not a reference.  Instead, you could just keep a reference of the object and get the isDead value from it as needed.

Note that there is by default no guarantee of the order of `Start` calls, so you should consider putting code that needs to run first in `Awake`.

Also, empty magic methods waste processing time. Get rid of any Update definitions rather than leave them empty.

Renaming your `Something` class to `Side` (surely that was a typo of some kind), it could look like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    Side sideOfSomething;
    public GameObject Something;
    void Start()
    {
        sideOfSomething = Something.GetComponent<Side>();
        Debug.Log(sideOfSomething.isDead);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       Debug.Log(sideOfSomething.isDead);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Side : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isDead;
    void Awake() // called prior to any Start
    {
        isDead = false;
    }

    // Empty magic methods waste cycles
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to change bool in update not in start
then you can see changed in isD value

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isD;
    public Something something;
    void Start()
    {

     something = GetComponent<Something>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       isD = something.isdead;
       Debug.Log(isD);
    }
}
```

Comment: no you should not do this ... at least no in this way! `GetComponent` is a quite expensive call and should not be done repeatedly and especially **never** in `Update`!

Comment: Please don't call `GetComponent` every frame in `Update`! This is a complete downgrade from my answer, which you don't even credit.